# Git pushing to a branch which has new branches from itself

Tags: git

I have created new branch from `master` and then another branch from new one:

```
master --> A --> B
```

Later I found out that some things should be fixed on branch `A`, so I went back there and maid those changes. Can I push those changes to branch `A` and later merge them with branch `B` (I know that I could make those changes on branch `B` directly, but I have made a mistake checking out branch `A` and now changes are here...) or should I create another branch from branch `A` and push those changes to that branch and later merge it with branch `B`?

```
master --> A --> B 
           |         
            ---> C
```

If both ways are possible, what would be the difference between them, is one way better then the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If no commits are made to branch `B` yet, you can simply make the fixes required on branch `A` and then merge it to branch `B`. This will not show a merge commit as there will be no commits on branch `B` to merge.
- Although, if there are commits made to branch `B`, you can either create a temporary branch (eg. `C`, `hotfix`) from branch `A`, then merge it with `A` and `B`, else you can directly make commits to branch `A` then merge with `B`. 
  Both these ways are correct, if the fixes are small, then you can directly commit on `A`, else make a new branch and go ahead.

Comment: Okay, thanks, as there are commits on branch `B`, but the changes are not that big, I'm gonna push changes to `A` directly. Will accept your answers asap.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have

1. created the first branch i.e `master`.
2. created a new branch `A` by selecting the `master` branch and take checkout using the command `git checkout -b A`
3. created another branch `B` by selecting the `A` branch and take checkout using the command `git checkout -b B`

Later, you want to change the code in branch A. Yes, you can push the changes, to do so, you should select the branch `A` by git command `git checkout A`. Make the changes and commit in branch `A`.

If you want to merge the changes of branch `A` in branch `B`, follow the steps:

1. Select the branch `B` using the git command `git checkout B`
2. Merge with branch `A` using the git command `git merge A`

You can find the current branch by using the git command `git branch`.

Yes, you can use both approaches to achieve your goal

1. make changes in Branch `A` and  merge with branch `B`
2. create a new branch from branch `A`, make the change in a new branch and merge with branch `B`.

In the 2nd approach, we are unnecessary creating an extra branch from branch `A`. 
FYI, If you merge branch `A` with branch `B`, it will not delete the branch `A`. Branch A still there unless until you delete the branch by using the git command `git branch -d source-branch`.

Comment: He is asking if the approach he suggests is right. He is not asking how to technically do it. Unfortunately, you are explaining what commands to use in order to achieve the state he describes, instead of actually advising whether he should do it or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in branch A and then rebase branch B.
Here is the information on how to rebase :
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing